# Oracle Script returning no rows

Tags: oracle, powerbuilder

I have a script that returns 0 rows for accurate data. I omit line 6 or 7 the script works. Is there anything logically incorrect with this script?

```
1 Select Max (seq_num)
2 From t_cap_history
3  Where pr_id_sak = :il_pr_id_sak
4     And re_unique_id=:locw_re_unique_id
5     And period_dte = :ll_period_date 
6     AND cap_from_dte = :ll_curr_from_date
7     And cap_to_dte = :ll_curr_to_date
8     And capitation_cde = :ls_cap_cde
```

Comment: You said omitting line 6 or 7 causes it to return results.  A) Did you mean AND instead of or? B) Given that these are dates, are you trying to do an exact match or do you want dates that are within a range?  Please give an example of the data you get when omitting one of the lines

Comment: What datatype is used for the `cap_from_dte` and `cap_to_dte` columns?

Answer (score 0):

Staring deeply into my crystal ball...

If `cap_from_dte` and `cap_to_dte` are columns of type `date`, then they will have a day component and a time component.  Even if your session isn't set to display the time component, it will be there.  You're doing an equality comparison so the `:ll_curr_from_date` and `:ll_curr_to_date` bind variables would need to match the data in the table exactly.  I would guess that your SQL*Plus session is set not to display the time portion of `date` values by default and that has caused you to pass incorrect values for your bind variables.

Assuming that your bind variables are dates with a time component of midnight (the default), you could use inequalities which generally make it easier for the optimizer to use indexes on the date columns

```
Select Max (seq_num)
  From t_cap_history
 Where pr_id_sak = :il_pr_id_sak
   And re_unique_id=:locw_re_unique_id
   And period_dte = :ll_period_date 
   AND cap_from_dte >= :ll_curr_from_date
   AND cap_from_dte <  :ll_curr_from_date + 1
   And cap_to_dte >= :ll_curr_to_date
   And cap_to_dte < :ll_curr_to_date + 1
   And capitation_cde = :ls_cap_cde
```

or you could use the `trunc` function to set the time component to midnight

```
Select Max (seq_num)
  From t_cap_history
 Where pr_id_sak = :il_pr_id_sak
   And re_unique_id=:locw_re_unique_id
   And period_dte = :ll_period_date 
   AND trunc(cap_from_dte) = :ll_curr_from_date
   And trunc(cap_to_dte) = :ll_curr_to_date
   And capitation_cde = :ls_cap_cde
```

Answer (score 0):

For date ranges why not

```
cap_to_dte >= :ll_curr_from_date AND cap_from_dte <= :ll_curr_to_date
```